# How to create a ScaleX ObjectAnimator with increasingly fast end?

Tags: android, android-animation, scale, interpolation, objectanimator

I'm developing a animation which must show a view increasing its size progressively more fast. I want to achieve the same effect that you see when a car is coming. When is far, the coming movement is slow, but the more near is the vehicle, the faster the car is for your vision.

When using ScaleX with ObjectAnimator, you have some possibilities of interpolation:

```
AccelerateDeccelerateInterpolator (default) -> very slow when the animation is close to finish...
AccelerateInterpolator -> Also slowing when the ScaleX is too much huge.
LinearInterpolator -> Even more slower when the ScaleX is too much huge.
FastOutSlowInInterpolator -> Still slow at the end.
```

How can the ScaleX animation get an effect of increasing speed of the scale with the time?

My sample code:

```
scaleX =  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.1f, 20f);        
scaleX.setDuration(10000);
scaleX.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
scaleX.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved creating a custom cubic bezier curve using this web: https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/

```
Interpolator customInterpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(cpX1,cpX2,cpY1,cpY2)
```

the resulting curve is similar to this:

```
     |
     |
_____/
```